# Remove duplicates based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

For the below given data set I want to remove the row which has later timestamp.

```
**37C1Z2990E5E0 (TRXID) should be UNIQUE** in the below dataSet

    JKLAMMSDF123    20141112    20141117    5000.0  P   1.22    RT101018    *2014-11-12 10:10:26*   37C1Z2990E5E0   101018
    JKLAMMSDF123    20141110    20141114    5000.0  P   1.22    RT161002    *2014-11-12 10:11:33*   37C1Z2990E5E0   161002

-- More rows
```

Comment: You can't have to identical values of PK in one table. Is this denormalized dataset?

Comment: Are you only interested in results with timestamp [BETWEEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) two others?

Comment: I meant we can take TRXID as a unique value and no duplicates are allowed

Comment: @tvelykyy yes it's denormalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH DATA AS
(
    SELECT TRXID, MAX(YourTimestampColumn) AS TS
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY TRXID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
DELETE T
FROM YourTable AS T
INNER JOIN DATA AS D
    ON T.TRXID = D.TRXID
   AND T.YourTimestampColumn = D.TS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the min of the timestamp column and group by all of the other columns.

```
SELECT MIN(TIMESTAMP), C1, C2, C3...
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY C1, C2, C3..
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do this by using `window function` plus `CTE`.

To check the result after removing duplicates use this.

```
;WITH DATA
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number()OVER(partition BY TRXID ORDER BY YourTimestampColumn) rn
         FROM   YourTable)
select * 
FROM data
WHERE  rn = 1
```

To `delete` the duplicates use this.

```
;WITH DATA
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number()OVER(partition BY TRXID ORDER BY YourTimestampColumn) rn
         FROM   YourTable)
DELETE FROM data
WHERE  rn > 1
```

This will work even if you more than one duplicate for same `TRXID`